# How to delete items in MongoRepository using query annotation?

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-data

I'm using Spring Data with MongoDB using MongoRepository.

I was wondering if it is possible do a delete by filter using query annotation. I have been looking here and google and I cannot find any documentation.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

```
@Query(value="{'id' : $0}", delete = true)
public Person deleteById (String id);
```

Comment: Thanks!, Worked for me. (was missing  "delete = true")

Comment: you can also use @DeleteQuery which does not require explicitly delete=true setting.

Answer (score 30):

Maybe you can use repository delete queries. Here is an example from [documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-mongo/docs/1.5.1.RELEASE/reference/html/mongo.repositories.html#mongodb.repositories.queries.delete):

```
public interface PersonRepository extends MongoRepository<Person, String> {
  List <Person> deleteByLastname(String lastname);

  Long deletePersonByLastname(String lastname);         
}
```

Using return type List will retrieve and return all matching documents before actually deleting them. A numeric return type directly removes the matching documents returning the total number of documents removed.

Comment: This appears to be the latest as of now so I think this should be the top answer.

Answer (score 4):

Try this, it's work for me.

```
@Repository
public interface DepartmentDao extends MongoRepository<Department, String> {
    @DeleteQuery
    void deleteByDepartment(String department);
}
```

OR

```
@Query(value="{'_id' : ?0}", delete = true)
public void deleteById(String id);
```

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately spring data doesn't provides any method to delete documents based on a query. And the `@Query` annotation is only for find documents.

What you could do is implement a [custom repository](http://static.springsource.org/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/reference/html/repositories.html#repositories.custom-implementations) that deletes documents based on what you want.

Comment: @Query works now for deleting. You add @Query(value = "{id: ?0}", delete = true) as Marcelo Pasut mentioned in answer.

Answer (score 3):

> How to delete a list of ids in the query ?

```
@Query(value="{idList : $0}", delete = true)
```

Comment: I recommend against answers in the shape of rethoric questions and against quoting questions in answers. Both puts the answer at risk of being mistaken for a question (at leat by lazy readers). Instead provide an explanation of how your solution works and why it solves the problem described in the question. That is anyway more appreciated here, because it also helps fighting the misconception that StackOverflow is a free codewriting service.

Answer (score 1):

Repository:

```
@Component
public interface SomeRepository extends MongoRepository<SomeObject, String> {

    @Query("{ '_id' : ?0 }")
    SomeObject findById(String _id);
}
```

Code in some class:

```
@Autowired
private SomeRepository pRepo;

public void delete(String id) {

    pRepo.delete(pRepo.findById(id));
}
```

Comment: This will result in 2 mongo queries instead of a single delete(criteria) one.

Answer (score 0):

```
@Repository
public interface DepartmentDao extends MongoRepository<Department, String> {
    void deleteByDepartment(String department);
}
```

is clean and shorter.

Answer (score 0):

Below code snippet show deletes all documents from the plan collection whose planId field matches any planId provided in the list.

```
@Repository
public interface PlanRepository extends MongoRepository<Plan, String> {

    @Query(value = "{ 'planId' : { $in : ?0 } }", delete = true)
  void deleteAllByPlanIdIn(List<String> planIds);
}
```

Explanation:

- we can use the `@Query` annotation to define custom queries on MongoDB data stores in Spring
- The "`value`" attribute specifies the MongoDB query in JSON-like syntax.
- "`planId`" is a field in the plan document being queried.
- "`{ $in : ?0 }`" is a query operator that checks if the value of the planId field is in the provided list of planIds ("`?0`" represents the first parameter of the method, which is the list of planIds).
- "`delete = true`" is used to indicate that the query is intended to be deleted.