# How to delete one object from the list in a document in Mongodb using Spring Boot Query?

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot

Please let me know how I can run the below Query using @Query Annotation in spring boot

```
db.removeObjectFromArrayDemo.update(
... {'_id': ObjectId("5c8ad13d6cea1f28b7aa0817")},
... { $pull: { "StudentAcademicProjectDetails" : { StudentProjectId: 101 } } },
... false,
... true
... );
```

Thanks is advance for helping me solve!.

Comment: Maybe the information on this link will help you - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17484153/how-to-delete-items-in-mongorepository-using-query-annotation

Comment: But the problem is that i only want to delete one particular entry not the entire column. The solution in the link is to delete the entire column